# How to create nested checkbox tile in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to create a filter screen which will have 1 checkbox and other checkbox inside it
like this
[image]

Comment: That's great, what have you done so far?

Comment: Are you using any state management solution?

Comment: no luck till now